# How to inline paragraph and nav

Tags: css, html

I can't figure out how to put the nav and the footer on the same line. I've tried changing the list margin, but this didn't work. I can't find what I'm doing wrong with the code below:

```css
ul {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=''>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=''>About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=''>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=''>Citations</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<footer style="color: white">
  <pre> 2016-2017 &copy; by Owner</pre>
</footer>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try `ul li a` as a selector?

Comment: Do you have to use a footer?

Comment: no, I'm just using it as a practice, but I do want to put the text inside 'pre' and I use 'pre' for spacing. I already try ul li

Comment: _"I do want to put the text inside 'pre' and I use 'pre' for spacing."_ — you _think_ you want to do that, because you're learning, but trust me, you _don't_ want to do spacing that way. CSS margins and padding are good for spacing. When more advanced you'll want to look at positioning (absolute, relative) and  _flex_ layout as well.

Answer (score 1):

put the nav inside the footer...

```
<footer>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><pre> 2016-2017 &copy; by Owner</pre></li>
      <li><a href=''>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=''>About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=''>Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href=''>Citations</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow both the **nav** and **footer** elements to render on the same line.

```
nav,
footer {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If you'd like them to also be centered within the browser window or region, you could add a wrapper element around them and apply **text-align: center;** to that wrapper element.

In order to space them out, you should alter the left/right margin accordingly.

Comment: It only aligned 'Citations' with the 'nav' the list is no longer inline.

Comment: Have a look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/phawley/pen/QKqqJp and let me know if this is what you're seeing (I removed the inline style for color: white on the footer so that I could see the text).

Comment: It's showing something like this.

Home </br>
About </br>
Contact </br>
Citations  2016-2017 &copy; by Owner.